# What is wrong with my findOne() implementation?

Tags: mongodb, deno, oak

I have followed all basic tutorials in search to fix this. My implementation of `collection.findOne({_id: ctx.params.id})` is just not working.

```
// import statements for version transparancy, they are not really used here
import { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.29.2/mod.ts";
import { Application, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/mod.ts";

// ...
const recipes = db.collection<Recipe>("recipes");

// ...
router.get("/rec/:id", async (ctx) => {
    const id = ctx.params.id;
    const recipe = await recipes.findOne({ _id: { $oid: id } });
    // const recipe = await recipes.findOne({_id: id});

    if (recipe) {
        ctx.response.status = 200;
        ctx.response.body = recipe;
    } else {
        ctx.response.status = 404;
        ctx.response.body = { message: "No recipe found" };
    }
});
```

Is there a current bug that I am not aware of?

Once I call that endpoint with `http://localhost:5000/rec/622b6be81089abbc4b4144a1` (and yes, that ID is in my database), I get an internal server error (500) with the following message:

```sh
[uncaught application error]: Error - MongoError: {"ok":0,"errmsg":"unknown operator: $oid","code":2,"codeName":"BadValue"}

request: {
  url: "http://localhost:5000/rec/622b6be81089abbc4b4144a1",
  method: "GET",
  hasBody: false
}
response: { status: 404, type: undefined, hasBody: false, writable: true }

    at WireProtocol.commandSingle (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.29.2/src/protocol/protocol.ts:44:13)
    at async FindCursor.executor (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.29.2/src/collection/commands/find.ts:17:24)
    at async FindCursor.execute (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.29.2/src/protocol/cursor.ts:34:21)
    at async FindCursor.next (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.29.2/src/protocol/cursor.ts:48:7)
    at async file:///home/andy/dev/deno/denodb/routes.ts:42:20
    at async dispatch (https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/middleware.ts:41:7)
    at async dispatch (https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/middleware.ts:41:7)
    at async dispatch (https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/middleware.ts:41:7)
    at async Application.#handleRequest (https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.4.0/application.ts:376:9)
```

Downgrading the version did not help either.

Comment: What is the value in `ctx.params.id`? Also, see the way to specify the `_id` value in the `find` filter: https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.29.2/README.md#find

Comment: The value is an ObjectId String and the `import {Bson} from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.29.2/mod.ts"` and usage like in the documentation fixed it - please provide an answer. so I can upvote it ️